# Out a value between the brackets in a function

Tags: python-3.x

```
from tkinter import *
import pygame.mixer

app = Tk()
app.title("Head First Mix")


sound_file = "50459_M_RED_Nephlimizer.wav"
mixer = pygame.mixer
mixer.init()

def track_start():
    track.play(loops = -1)

def track_stop():
    track.stop()

def shutdown():
    track.stop()
    app.destroy()

def track_toogle():
    if track_playing.get() == 1:
        track_start()
    else:
        track_stop()

def change_volume(v):

    track.set_volume(volume.get())



track_playing = IntVar()

track = mixer.Sound(sound_file)

track_button = Checkbutton(app,
                           variable = track_playing,
                           command = track_toogle,
                           text = "50459_M_RED_Nephlimizer.wav")


track_button.pack(side = LEFT)

volume = DoubleVar()

volume.set(track.get_volume())

volume_scale = Scale(app,
                     variable = volume,
                     from_ = 0.0,
                     to = 1.0,
                     resolution = 0.1,
                     command = change_volume,
                     label = "Volume",
                     orient = HORIZONTAL)

volume_scale.pack(side = RIGHT)

app.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", shutdown)

app.mainloop()
```

for the moment i read a book called head first python. i understoop everything until i reached chapter 9. why dont my app work if i dont place something in the change_volume functions brackets

why do i need the"v" - 
    def change_volume(v):

The let you stop, start and adjust volume for a track btw

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
def change_volume(v):

    track.set_volume(volume.get())
```

is written to require a parameter `v`. However, as written, it never actually uses the parameter. Instead, since you called `volume = track.get_volume()` elsewhere in the code, unless you modify `volume` (or the value of the track's volume) somewhere else, your code is effectively equivalent to

```
def change_volume(v):

    track.set_volume(track.get_volume())
```

If you want to actually change the value, you need to use the value of the parameter to set the volume:

```
def change_volume(v):

    track.set_volume(v.get())
```

Comment: So, if i do not misunderstand i need the parameter because teh value of volume.get changes?

Comment: Looking closer at the code, it looks like you set the value of `volume` to be the result of `track.get_volume()` elsewhere in the code. If you were to call `change_volume(v)` as written in your code, it would ignore the parameter and call `track.set_volume(volume.get())`; the problem here is that since `volume.get()` currently returns the same value as `track.get_volume()`. It would essentially be like calling `track.set_volume(track.get_volume())`, changing nothing. In the definition of `change_volume`, you need to use the value of the parameter to set the volume properly.

Comment: Looking at it again, I'm not familiar with the `Scale` object. Is the `command` parameter used when the user adjusts the slider, using the value of the slider as the parameter for `set_volume`? If so, then the change I suggested should do the trick. If not, you'll need to figure out how to take the value of the slider when it changes and pass it to `set_volume` (ensuring that you use the value of the parameter when setting the track's volume, of course).